# Analogue of location.hash's hashchange event for pushState

Tags: javascript, address-bar

Before the days of [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), it was common to use `window.location.hash` to set the hash in the address bar, and [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to listen to the user editing the hash in the address bar manually, both without causing a page reload. Now, with the history API, it's possible to change the whole URL via [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) and such, but I don't know of a way to listen to the user editing the whole URL in the address bar manually. Is there an analogue to `onhashchange` that can catch manual changes to the address bar, and cause updates to the page without reloading? Obviously, for security reasons, this can't possibly exist if the user were to change the domain, but I'm wondering if a way exists if the domain remains the same.